# call_user_func_array() conflict with php 5.3

Tags: php, wordpress

**Hello programmers**

I have a problem with WordPress version 4.7, recently I updated my Website WordPress platform to new version and it gives me a warning message on my website homepage. This is the warning message:

> Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid
>   callback, no array or string given in
>   /home/kvlkclir/english.kvlkcl.ir/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line
>   298

And here is where it points to:

```
if ( $the_['accepted_args'] == 0 ) {
                $value = call_user_func_array( $the_['function'], array() );
            } elseif ( $the_['accepted_args'] >= $num_args ) {
                $value = call_user_func_array( $the_['function'], $args);
            } else {
                $value = call_user_func_array( $the_['function'], array_slice( $args, 0, (int)$the_['accepted_args'] ) );
            }
```

I saw php.net and figure out that it's because of **call_user_func_array** syntax in php 5.3 (I'm using php 5.3). I know a little about php and therefor couldn't fixed the warning on my website if some one can tell me what should I do I appreciate it.

**Thank you**

---

Here is the whole code:

```
public function apply_filters( $value, $args ) {
    if ( ! $this->callbacks ) {
        return $value;
    }
    $nesting_level = $this->nesting_level++;
    $this->iterations[ $nesting_level ] = array_keys( $this->callbacks );
    $num_args = count( $args );
    do {
        $this->current_priority[ $nesting_level ] = $priority = current( $this->iterations[ $nesting_level ] );
        foreach ( $this->callbacks[ $priority ] as $the_ ) {
            if( ! $this->doing_action ) {
                $args[ 0 ] = $value;
            }
            if ( $the_['accepted_args'] == 0 ) {
                $value = call_user_func_array( $the_['function'], array() );
            } elseif ( $the_['accepted_args'] >= $num_args ) {
                $value = call_user_func_array( $the_['function'], $args);
            } else {
                $value = call_user_func_array( $the_['function'], array_slice( $args, 0, (int)$the_['accepted_args'] ) );
            }
        }
    } while ( false !== next( $this->iterations[ $nesting_level ] ) );

    unset( $this->iterations[ $nesting_level ] );
    unset( $this->current_priority[ $nesting_level ] );
    $this->nesting_level--;
    return $value;
}
```

Comment: Are you using call_user_func_array in class?.  I got this error in my development. I used 'call_user_method('call_func',$this, $args);

Comment: as I said I know little about php but I can see that "call_user_func_array" is used in the Do While commend. I put the whole code in the question part on the top

Comment: Please try with call_user_method

Comment: What exactly is in Your `$the_['function']`? Can You `var_dump()` it for us?

Comment: @vel You can't use `call_user_method` since it is deprecated. `call_user_func`, `call_user_func_array` are the only alternatives you can use.

Comment: what is the value of $the_ array?. can you post the value?